# PHP/MySQL select a database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

Think this should be an easy one. I understand how to establish a connection, eg:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
```

Where `localhost` is the database type, `peter` is the user and `abc123` the password but how do you specify the actual database? For example, I have 3 databases on my server. How do I specify database2?

Comment: And what if you started by reading the [PHP manual](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/index.php) first?

Comment: a simple www search would have given you the answer :(

Comment: @kmindi thats what I did first off, of course, and it didnt give me a satisfactory one, hence the question

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?q=php+mysql+select+database was not satisfactory, okey ...

Comment: The PHP manual is a complete and organized reference for all PHP functions.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @kmindi hmm honestly whatever I entered only revealed the mysql_connect stuff above... yes I should have search harder

Comment: @MeltinDog please consinder your selection of the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there are so many answers that suggest `mysql_select_db('database1');` and its getting more upvotes I'll try to create a complete answer:

**Don't use `mysql_select_db('database1');` !**
(You should not use it in new development projects because it is in deprecation process)

Use one of the following ways:

Either you use PDO like this:

```
<?php
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
        foreach ($dbh->query('SELECT * from FOO') as $row) {
            print_r($row);
        }
        $dbh = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
?>
```

Or you could use mysqli:

```
<?php
   $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "database", 3306);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using mysql_select_db()

```
mysql_select_db("database");
```

Consider using Mysqli or PDO as the mysql extension is being supported less and less.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use `mysql_select_db`. Here's a [basic example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php) from the manual:

```
// Connecting, selecting database
$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_select_db('my_database') or die('Could not select database');
```

Please note that `mysql_*` functions are being deprecated, and their use is discouraged. You should either use the [`mysqli_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) family or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), read more about [choosing a MySQL API on the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mysql_select_db("DBNAME") or die('Could not select database');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mysql_select_db`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php). I'm going to also jump on the normal bandwagon and suggest you learn PDO or mysqli instead though, since the normal mysql interface is currently deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the different database in a server using like this

```
$conn1 = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123"); 
$conn2 = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123"); 

mysql_select_db('database1', $conn1);
mysql_select_db('database2', $conn2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could better use mysqli like bellow :-

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database_name");
```

**It is recommended to use either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extensions. It is not recommended to use the old mysql extension for new development. A detailed feature comparison matrix is provided below. The overall performance of all three extensions is considered to be about the same. Although the performance of the extension contributes only a fraction of the total run time of a PHP web request. Often, the impact is as low as 0.1%.**